# How to connect to Pervasive files with ODBC?

Tags: odbc, pervasive

I'm on Azure and I would like to access a Pervasive database with PHP ODBC. I've got the information from mirtheil that there has to be a so called engine installed as well in order to be able to access the database. I've checked the installed apps where I've found a zen control center (or zen monitor) where I can see an engine, but it's very strange. There are 3 default databases defined (I can access these with ODBC), but these seem like nothing to have to do with the data im looking for. Now as I understand, the Pervasive database is no database like an RDBMS but a bunch of text files. I can see some of these that are actually in use. Under active files it says 400+ active microkernel files. I think these are the ones I need. Now how do access these with ODBC? Could you please pont me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

To access data through ODBC, a Database must be created.  When creating the database, you will point the database to the DDF files (FILE.DDF, FIELD.DDF, and INDEX.DDF at a minimum) and the Data files.  The definition of the database name is:

> A named database (also called a DBname) is a database with a logical
> name that allows users to identify it without knowing its location.
> Zen requires that all databases be named. When you name a database,
> you associate that name with a particular dictionary directory path
> and one or more data file paths. A named database is connected to
> through various access methods. For ODBC access, for example, you must
> set up a data source name (DSN) to refer to the named database.
> Multiple DSNs may point to the same named database. See ODBC Database
> Access in ODBC Guide. For other access methods, application developers
> can connect to a named database using the API for that access method.
> Refer to the developer reference guides in the Zen documentation.

as documented at https://docs.actian.com/zen/v15/index.html#page/advops/creatingdb.htm#ww69486
Creating a Database can be done using the following steps:

1. In Zen Explorer, right-click the database engine where you want the
   new database and select New > Database. In the Create New Database
   dialog box, provide a database name and location (see Identifier
   Restrictions).
2. The name cannot match an existing DSN. Also, no two data files in a
   directory can share a file name and differ only by file name
   extension. For example, invoice.btr and invoice.mkd are not allowed
   in the same directory because the database engine ignores the
   extension and sees them as the same file.
3. Set database and DSN options. See New Database GUI Reference for
   information about the options.

The data files are not text files.  There is an individual file for each table.  Those files can be access using ODBC (or other relational methods) or through the Btrieve (or other Transactional methods) interface.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to check this Right away, however I don't have DDF files, only .KEY and . DTK and .DBVAR. do I have to create from these with the DDF builder the DDF files first?

Comment: You need DDFs to use ODBC.  The DDFs describe the data files.  If this is a third-party app, contact them for DDFs.  If it's an in-house / custom app, you should still contact a technical resource for the file structure.  You can try using DDF Builder to create the entries for the table but you need to know exactly how the fields (length and data type) are defined.

Comment: Thank you. I have the exact definitions actually so that should be no problem. If I build the DDF files, it's not going to affect the data or how the app itself is working, right? If I would still don't manage to create the DDFs what other options do we have to access these files (maybe without ODBC)?

Comment: The DDFs themselves will not affect the data in the data files or the app itself  If you modify the data through ODBC, it would modify the data in the app.  Without ODBC, you can use the Btrieve interface would access the data without DDFs.  Other interfaces (ActiveX, PHP, ADO.NET, PDAC, JDBC, etc) all use DDFs.

Comment: I created a new database in Zen DDF builder, specified the path where the .DTK and .KEY files are. These files are realized as relevant somehow, and I assume I have to right-click on them and create table definition. But then I'm getting btrieve error 176. Btrieve OPEN failed. Any ideas?

Comment: https://support.elliott.com/knowledgebase/articles/834963-btrieve-error-codes-001-199 says: 176: File or table not specified in URI
An Open or Create was issued using a URI connection string that contained neither a file name nor a table name. - unfortunately it says nothing for me. Interestingly, when I go one level  higher in the file tree, I can create tables out of those DTK files. Could it be an authorization issue...?

Comment: I guess I have figured it out! There is an underscore in the path and it's not allowed along with many others.

Comment: Now the only problem is that what I need actually are the DAT files and zen DDF builder doesn't seem to be able to see them.